# Updating embedded documents in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user and a premium schema. The premium one is embedded in user.

```js
const premiumSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    subscriptionID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    guild: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
    payment_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    expiry: {
      type: Date,
      require: true,
    },
    reminded: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { collection: "premium" }
);
```

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  discordId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  accessToken: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  premium: {
    type: [premiumSchema],
    required: false,
  },
});
```

I am trying to update a value of my premium collection by:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({
    "premium._id": new ObjectId(req.body.premiumId),
});
const premium = user.premium.id(new ObjectId(req.body.premiumId));
premium.reminded = true;
await user.save();
```

The Problem is that it updates the `reminded` attribute in my `user.premium` array but doesn't update it in the premium collection itself. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use findOneAndUpdate method and positional operator to directly update your user.

Positional operator $ allows you to iterate through the array and update only the corresponding subdocument

```
const savedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: new ObjectId(req.body.premiumId)},
  {$set: {'premium.$.reminded': true}}
);
```

See doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

This way you can update the subdocument within the User collection, but **the value in the Premium collection will not be updated**.
This is because when you define the premium property within the Users collection you are telling mongoose (and mongodb) to save the object within the user collection itself.
In this case there are no references between the two collections: the data will be saved only in the user collection, intended as subdocuments.
You are just defining schema for child won't create a separate collection for the children in the database instead you will embed the whole child document in the parent (user).

Example data:

```
user1: {
  discordId: { 'abc' },
  accessToken: { 'token' },
  premium: {
    subscriptionID: { 'idSubscription' } 
    guild: { },
    payment_id: { 'idPayment' },
    expiry: { '2021-07-31T20:41:19.618+00:00' },
    reminded: { true }
  },
});
```

The two User and Premium collections remain completely separate.
If you want to upgrade the Premium collection as well, you can do it using two different calls, one for User and one for Premium.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i know there are many ways of updating array of embedded documents. But my problem is that mongoose only updates the attribute in embedded document only. It doesn't update it in the collection (in my case its premium collection) ?

Comment: I got it now. I thought that mongoose will do that for me. Thankyou very much.